# Confusion regarding notation on a matrix which have $I$ as an element

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

I'm given this transformation matrix for a linear map between two general vector spaces. I've never seen this notation before:

$\begin{bmatrix}
I &0 \\ 
 0& 0
\end{bmatrix}$, where I is the identity matrix "of a certain size" (whatever that means).

Should it be read as a $2x2$ matrix which actually have a identity matrix in position (1,1) or should it be read as something else, maybe (any) identity matrix but with zeroes in the column to the right and the lowest row?

Comment: It's a block matrix, so $\mathbf{I}$ is the identity matrix and the $\mathbf{0}$'s are themselves matrices (of all zeros) of given sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a block matrix, so $\mathbf{I}$ is the identity matrix and the $\mathbf{0}$'s are themselves matrices (of all zeros) of given sizes.

If $\mathbf{I}\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$ and the overall block matrix is in $\mathbb{R}^{M\times N}$, then the bottom right $\mathbf{0}$ will be in $\mathbb{R}^{(M-2) \times (N-2)}$, the bottom left $\mathbf{0}$ will be in $\mathbb{R}^{(M-2)\times 2}$, and the top right $\mathbf{0}$ will be in $\mathbb{R}^{2\times (N-2)}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard notation, the zeros in your matrix are also matrix (of zeros)